# Does using useCallback have any benefit when creating an object with some props that never change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that needs a configuration object (a simple alert/popup with some buttons and actions) and I started cleaning up some code to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

I'm declaring the option object like

```
const optionToLogoutAlert = {
    title: 'Logout',
    action: logoutHandler
}
```

Some object I'm able to declare outside the component function because it contains only some static props. But there are others that need some functions or context.
I can declare them outside and pass those functions through props or I can declare them as a useCallback.

```
const optionToLogoutAlert = useCallback( () => {
    return {
        title: 'Logout',
        action: logoutHandler
    }
}, [])
```

Or I can declare it outside the component and pass the needed function by props

```
const optionToLogoutAlert = (logoutHandler) {
    return {
         title: 'Logout',
         action: logoutHandler
    }
}

export default function ComponentThaUseAlert(props) { ...
```

Does the constant re-declaring of the option object come with some drawback? Have some benefits the use of useCallback o declaring it outside the component? What's the appropriate approach to this?

Comment: Use useCallback if you create a callback that relies on state which will have changed when the callback is used?

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide more clarity about what you're comparing? But if I'm reading right: If the function doesn't use any of the component state (not even state setters), then create it outside the component and reuse it. If it uses component state (and you can't pass that to it as an argument), you have to create it within the component so it has access to that state.

Comment: Separately: `useCallback` is primarily useful for avoiding unnecessary re-renders of components that take the function as a prop, **if** those components optimize re-rendering by comparing with previous props (e.g., `React.memo`, `PureComponent`, `shouldComponentUpdate`).

Comment: Yeah, but the constant "re-declaration" of all of those functions don't really matters? Anyway, reading a bit more found that the useCallback also get re-declared.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid seeing `useCallback` as a blanket performance optimization.
the benefit of `useCallback` and `useMemo` is preventing re-rendering and these hooks are caching the dependencies and compare with previous props if you don't have states that cause re-rendering you don't need to use theme because of performance reasons.